# How to programatically launch Microphone Volume control panel in Windows Vista?

Tags: audio, windows-vista

I want to let the user adjust the Mic volume. Rather than reinventing the wheel, we (in XP) would just launch the Volume control panel (by running sndvol32.exe).

You can bring up the *Speaker* Volume control in Win **Vista** by shelling out to : 
SndVol.exe

*In XP you could specify a command line parameter -R to show Microphone volume.*

Anyone know what the command line parameter is for SndVol.exe to show Mic volume for **Windows Vista**?

Or some other way to display the Mic volume control panel?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think what you want is "control.exe mmsys.cpl,,1"

> If you want to access the Mixer and
>   the other functions, you can use these
>   shortcuts:
>  • Master Volume Left:
>   SndVol.exe -f 0
>  • Master Volume
>   Right: SndVol.exe -f 49825268
>  •
>   Volume Mixer Left: SndVol.exe -r 0
>   • Volume Mixer Right: SndVol.exe -r
>   49490633
>  • Playback Devices:
>   control.exe mmsys.cpl,,0
>  •
>   Recording Devices: control.exe
>   mmsys.cpl,,1
>  • Sounds: control.exe
>   mmsys.cpl,,2
>   From http://www.errorforum.com/microsoft-windows-vista-error/4636-vista-tips-tricks-tweaks.html

Comment: This is very close (and perhaps the best that one can get with Vista) but it doesn't show volume. User would need to select the recording device, click configure, then got through a wizard which eventually gets them volume.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little confused by your question. This brings up the Recording window for me ([ref](http://demins.blogspot.com/2007/06/windows-xp-volume-control-from-command.html)):

```
sndvol32 -record
```

Are you trying to hide all mixers but one?